# non-local variables in java

Tags: java, variables, object

pls, can someone explain with examples what "non-local" variables are in java?

My Understanding
   Non-local variables are object variables. But when called object variables would that be referring to the variables used in the object methods?

Comment: The term 'non-local variable' is not typically used in Java. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html  gives you an outline of what's what.

Answer (score 2):

In Java Programming language, [there are 4 kinds of variables.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

Local Variables : These are variables that are declared within method scope. A method will often store its temporary state in local variables.

If you ask for **Non-Local** variables, then you'd refer to all other variables but local; like

1. Instance Variables (Non-Static Fields)
2. Class Variables (Static Fields)
3. Parameters

Answer (score 1):

Instance variables(non-local) are declared in a class, but outside a method, constructor or any block.Instance variables belong to an instance of a class, Every object has it’s own copy of the instance variables

```
public class InstanceClassSample {

    String name = "Java";

    public void testName(){

        //instanceClassSample and instanceClassSample2 will have it own copy of name 

        InstanceClassSample instanceClassSample = new InstanceClassSample();
        InstanceClassSample instanceClassSample2 = new InstanceClassSample();

        System.out.println(instanceClassSample.name);
        System.out.println(instanceClassSample2.name);      

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

A local variable will be declared within `{` and `}` of a method. Outside the the braces, the variable will no longer be accessible and garbage collected.
As far as I know object variable is not really a thing in Java, you can have an instance variable or a class variable, those would technically be your 'non-local' variables.